# Java Runtime Execute different inside program than in command line?

Tags: java, linux, runtime, runtime.exec

Im trying to compile some java files using the Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command) and im generating the command. The code below shows what i am doing:

```
String command = "javac ";
    for(String s: this.getPackages())
    {
        command = command + "/home/benuni/CompileFiles/" + project + "/" + s + "/*.java ";
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("command: '"+ command +"'");
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         printLines(" stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());

        pro.waitFor();
```

This is giving the following output:

```
command: 'javac /home/benuni/CompileFiles/HelloWorldProject/HelloWorldPackage/*.java '
stderr: javac: file not found:     /home/benuni/CompileFiles/HelloWorldProject/HelloWorldPackage/*.java
 stderr: Usage: javac <options> <source files>
 stderr: use -help for a list of possible options
```

and its not working.. but if i copy the command into my shell, it works no problem... any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing *.java with any one file that is in /home/benuni/CompileFiles/HelloWorldProject/HelloWorldPackage/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't expand the `*` wildcard for you.  That's a facility of the shell.  Instead, you'll need to list the directory to get all of the contained files.

Something like this would do the trick to build up your command:

```
    File[] files = new File("/home/benuni/CompileFiles/" + project + "/" + s).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".java");
        }
    });

    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("javac");
    for(File file : files) {
        command.append(" ").append(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you enter from the command line, the command analyzer expands `*` into a list of files.  When you use Runtime.exec that expansion does not occur, and you must explicitly specify the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to provide the actual list of file names to javac. Another is to let shell do it, using the command

```
/bin/sh -c javac /home/benuni/CompileFiles/HelloWorldProject/HelloWorldPackage/*.java
```